# Prevent explosion particle effect clipping through terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles

I have implemented blast particle within my game but when it spawns, it gets cutout to correspond to the nearest environment object.

This problem, I was getting:
[image]

Overall there are multiple particle systems are running to achieve this but I am attaching one particle system inspector panel details:

[image]

A similar kind of renderer exists for mostly all particle systems. So please guide me to solve the above effect cut related problem with the wall.

**EDIT-1:**

I have added a VFX rendering camera and created separate later too for the effects but there is no change in the result.
[image]

**EDIT-2**:

Here you have a screenshot for the Main Camera of the game:
[image]

Comment: how wide is that "wall" type thing its showing through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this advice on the [polycount forums](https://polycount.com/discussion/comment/2044153/#Comment_2044153) written by user AlecMoody:

> [1.] Create a second camera parented to the primary camera...
>
> [2.] Create a render layer for your [particle effect] (or assign it to an existing layer).
>
> [3.] Set the main camera culling mask to everything except your explosion layer.
>
> [4.] Set the child camera culling mask to only be your explosion layer. The child camera should have the clear flag set to "don't clear"
>
> [5.] and put a positive value into the [child] camera depth.

Since for you having a higher depth on the child camera doesn't make it render above the lower depth cameras, setting the clear flag to "depth only" may help you.

Comment: So apart from adding another camera, there is no option exist to solve this problem? because my 3d camera following a player and doing other tasks too.

Comment: Nobody said this was the only way. How does your camera doing other things matter? Did you try this answer?

Comment: If you're asking if theres just an option "cullParticlesOutOfPointOfView = true` or something like that, then no.

Comment: I have updated my question after applying the above solution.

Comment: @Siddharth what's the depth on the main camera? it should be something less than 1

Comment: Minimap camera depth = -1, Main camera depth = 0, VFX camera depth = 1

Comment: @Siddharth we need more information about how you are rendering the cameras to the viewport. Please include the inspector of the main camera in the question.

Comment: @Ruzihm If I change the camera flag from "Don't Clear" to "Depth Only" then there is no cut in the particle system when it hit the wall - is this proper solution?

Comment: @Siddharth I'm not sure why that's happening but I've edited the answer to include that. I could make a more informed answer if you shared the inspector for your main camera.

Comment: @Ruzihm okay, I will share screenshot tomorrow with you and really thank you for all your support :)

Comment: @Ruzihm I have added details for the Main Camera within the question...

Answer (score 1):

You could add collisions to the particles so that they either bounce away from the world object or are just destroyed.

**Example Collision Setup**

[image]

It will add a little overhead but depending on how many particles the effect uses it shouldn't be an issue, and if it is you could test it with a lower collision quality.